# Java RegEx pattern is invalid when trying to exclude commas

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm building a function to validate usernames, and in this case I want to accept alphabetic characters only. I'm matching the provided user input against this regex:

```
[1-9!@#$%&*()_+=|<>?{}\\[\\]~-,]
```

This is the method that makes use of the regex:

```
public static String purgeInvalidLogin(String failedLogin, String pattern) {
    Pattern special = Pattern.compile (pattern);
    String purgedLogin = failedLogin.replaceAll(special.pattern(), ""); // remove any special characters before moving on
    purgedLogin = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(purgedLogin);
    return purgedLogin;
}
```

However when trying to run this I get this message:

> Illegal character range near index 25 [!@#$%&*()_+=|<>?{}[]~-,] ^

which only happened once I added the comma. I've also tried the expression [!@#$%&*()_+=|<>?{}[]~-\,] (escaping the comma) to no avail. I'm wondering how I can use the regex properly to exclude commas making use of my method above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to accept only alpha chars and you are doing this by listing every possible illegal character? Have you not got this backwards? Would it not be better to look for what you do want and flag non matches?

Comment: @Dave - read this question quite rapidly, and missed the obvious comment you've made here. This should be the correct answer for this question, why don't you add as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear in my question. This isn't for detecting the invalid username, but it's a requirement to provide suggestions to the user if their username won't work. I want to build the suggestions off of their original desired username, but I can't include the invalid characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the hyphen just before it. It is interpreted as defining a range of characters, as soon as you add another character (the comma) after it.

```
[1-9!@#$%&*()_+=|<>?{}\\[\\]~\\-,]
```

Comment: alternately he could put the hyphen at the end of the string of characters, but that does pose the risk that down the road somebody will add another character and run into this problem again.  Escaping is better, just thought it would be useful for his understanding to add this comment

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'd also be tempted to escape the hyphen even if it's at the end. Not necessary, but makes the intention clear and protects against this sort of thing.

Comment: Agreed... I wouldn't just be tempted to escape the hyphen at the end, I'd recommend it

Answer (score 0):

You want to accept only alpha chars and you are doing this by listing every possible illegal character. I think you have got this backwards and it would better to look for what you do want (which would be a much shorter regex) and flag non matches.

Comment: Dave, please read the comments below yours associated with the original question; I think they might relieve your doubts.